# How to combine two IsNull condition in IF expression in Qlikview?

Tags: if-statement, expression, qlikview, isnull

I have three column as A, B, C

I'm writing an expression for column D in Qlikview to find out whenever column B & C IsNull I need to replace the value of C in column D. Similarly Vice versa for the remaining columns.

**Expression:**

=if((IsNull(A) and IsNull(B)), C,if((IsNull(B) and IsNull(C)), A,.....)

But I'm not getting the values in my output.

Was there any issue in the above expression ?

Can someone help me on it .

Comment: I am not fully understanding the requirement. So If a & b isnull then c? What if b is not null? Do you want to select the first column that is not null? EDIT: also is this a numeric or varchar field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if (rangesum(len(A),len(B))=0,C,if (rangesum(len(B),len(C))=0,A,.....
```

`isNull` is a problematic functions and many times does behave as expected.
It is best practice to use `Len()` instead.

also make sure you have a single value in `A,B,C` per row, otherwise it will not work

Comment: Thanks EldadT for the Answer. It Works. Also I have used nested If loops . Expressions:  if(IsNull(A),if(IsNull(B), C), if(IsNull(B), if(IsNull(C), A),.....). It also works.